# Data table drop down breaking in my application

Tags: javascript, datatable, ejs

I have a simple data table ([Data Tables by Cloud Tables](https://datatables.net)) implementation, much like the one mentioned in the documentation, but as the view changes to mobile or tab view, the drop down (show _ entries) breaks, i.e., the drop down is misplaced. I have tried to over-ride the CSS, apply additional styles and even use FixedHeader plugin but it remains the same.

I have attached a screen shot of the issue below. Please help me find a solution.

Screenshot of Bug:

[image]

I tried to implement a data table with two filters (search and number of entries). Number of entries is a drop down. Everything works but the number of entries drop down break when I enter mobile view or Tab view.

This is my DataTable implementation:

```
const sampleTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    fixedHeader: {
      css: {
        display: 'flex !important'
      }
    },
    dom: '<"row"<"#colVisDiv.col-sm-6 col-md-6 white-text-btn"B><"#lengthSelDiv.col-sm-6 col-md-6"l><"#filtersButtonDiv.col-sm-6 col-md-6"><"#searchDiv.col-sm-6 col-md-6"fr>>tip',
    ajax: {
      url: 'sample/route',
      type: 'GET',

      oLanguage: {
        sEmptyTable: "Table is empty"
      },
      
      dataSrc: function(json) {
        return json.data;
      }
    },
    responsive: {
      details: {
        display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRowImmediate
      }
    },
    stateSave: true,
    pageLength: 25,
    paging: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    deferRender: true,
    order: [
      [0, 'desc']
    ],
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {

      // checkLiveCalls();
      $('div.dataTables_filter input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');    

      $('.buttons-colvis')[0].innerHTML = $('.buttons-colvis')[0].textContent
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var filterWrapper = $('<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center" id="filter_' + this.index() + '" style="margin-bottom:20px;"> <h5> ' + this.header().innerHTML + ' </h5> </div>').appendTo($("#filters")[0]);
        var select = $('<select style="font-size:20px; min-width:200px; max-width:200px;"><option value="">ALL</option></select>')
          .appendTo($('#filter_' + this.index())[0])
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );

            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          if (d !== null) {
            if (d == '0')
              select.append('<option value="TestOne">TestOne</option>');
            else if (d == '2')
              select.append('<option value="TestTwo">TestTwo</option>');
            else
              select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
          }

        });
      });
    },
    columns: [{
        data: 'id',
        title: 'Column One',
        responsivePriority: 0,
        className: "noVis"
      },
      {
        data: 'column_two',
        title: '<%=columnTwo%>',
        responsivePriority: 1,
        className: "noVis",
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return validUrlCallPanel(data);
        }
      },
      {
        target: 2,
        responsivePriority: 4,
        className: "noVis",
        data: 'column_three',
        title: 'Column Three',
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          if (data !== null) {
            const time = new Date(data).toString("en-US", {
              timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"
            });
            const now = time.toString().slice(0, 24);
            return now;
          } else return '';
        }
      },
      {
        target: 3,
        responsivePriority: 6,
        className: "noVis",
        data: 'column_four',
        title: 'Column Four',
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          if (data !== null) {
            const time = new Date(data).toString("en-US", {
              timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"
            });
            const timePart = data.substring(11, data.length - 5);
            const now = time.slice(0, 11);
            const timeArray = timePart.split(':');
            let hoursPart = timeArray[0];
            let timeOfDay = 'AM';
            if (hoursPart == '12') timeOfDay = 'PM';
            if (parseInt(hoursPart) > 12) {
              if (hoursPart == '24')
                hoursPart = '12';
              else {
                hoursPart = parseInt(hoursPart) - 12;
                hoursPart = '0' + hoursPart;
                timeOfDay = 'PM';
              }
            }

            return now + ' ' + hoursPart + ':' + timeArray[1] + ' ' + timeOfDay;
          } else return '';
        }
      },
      {
        target: 4,
        responsivePriority: 1,
        className: "noVis",
        data: 'column_five',
        title: 'Column Five',
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          let dispositionBadge = '';
          if (row.status === 2 || row.status === 3) {
            dispositionBadge += '<div class="text-white mr-2 badge badge-secondary">';
            dispositionBadge += row.status === 2 || row.status === 3 ? encodeToHtmlChar(data): '';
            dispositionBadge += '</div>';
          }
          return dispositionBadge;
        }
      },
      {
        target: 5,
        responsivePriority: 2,
        className: "noVis",
        data: 'column_six',
        title: 'Column Six',
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return data;
        }
      },
      {
        target: 6,
        data: "column_seven",
        className: "noVis",
        title: 'Column Seven',
        responsivePriority: 3
      },
      {
        data: 'column_eight',
        title: 'Column Eight',
        responsivePriority: 7,
        visible: false,
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return dataReturnFunction(data);
        }
      },
      {
        data: 'column_nine',
        title: 'Column Nine',
        responsivePriority: 8,
        visible: false,
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return dataReturnFunction(data);
        }
      },
      {
        data: 'column_ten',
        title: 'Column Ten',
        responsivePriority: 9,
        visible: false,
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return dataReturnFunction(data);
        }
      },
      {
        data: 'column_eleven',
        title: 'Column Eleven',
        responsivePriority: 10,
        visible: false,
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return dataReturnFunction(data);
        }
      },
      {
        data: 'column_twelve',
        title: 'Column Twelve',
        responsivePriority: 11,
        visible: false,
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return dataReturnFunction(data);
        }
      },
      {
        data: 'column_thirteen',
        title: 'Column Thirteen',
        responsivePriority: 12,
        visible: false,
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return dataReturnFunction(data);
        }
      },
      {
        data: 'column_fourteen',
        title: 'Column Fourteen',
        responsivePriority: 13,
        visible: false,
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return dataReturnFunction(data);
        }
      },
      {
        data: 'column_fifteen',
        title: 'Column Fifteen',
        responsivePriority: 14,
        visible: false,
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return dataReturnFunction(data);
        }
      },
      {
        data: 'column_sixteen',
        title: 'Column Sixteen',
        responsivePriority: 15,
        visible: false,
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return dataReturnFunction(data);
        }
      },

    ],

    columnDefs: [{
      searchPanes: {
        show: false,
      },
      targets: "_all",
    }],
    buttons: [{
        className: 'btn-sm',
        extend: 'colvis',
        columns: ':not(.noVis)',
        text: 'Fields'
      },
      {
        className: 'btn-sm',
        extend: 'searchPanes',
        config: {
          cascadePanes: false,
          columns: [],
          threshold: 1,
          layout: 'columns-1',
          controls: false,
          panes: [{
            header: 'Sample',
            options: [{
                label: 'No Sample',
                value: function(rowData, rowIdx) {
                  return rowData["Sample"] === null;
                }
              },
              <% for(let i = 0; i<JSON.parse(Sample).length; i++) {%> {
                label: JSON.parse('<%- Sample %>')[<%- i %>].value,
                value: function(rowData, rowIdx) {
                  return encodeToHtmlChar(rowData["Sample"]) == JSON.parse('<%- Sample %>')[<%- i %>].value;
                }
              },
              <% } %>
            ],
            dtOpts: {
              paging: false,
            }
          }]
        },
        text: 'Filters'
      }
    ],
    language: {
      searchPanes: {
        collapse: {
          0: 'Sample',
          _: 'Sample (%d Sample)'
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.